# How to manage the velocity with my PanResponder?

Tags: react-native, gesture, nsresponder

I'm trying to use the [PanGestureHandler](https://kmagiera.github.io/react-native-gesture-handler/docs/handler-pan.html) api from the `react-native-gesture-handler` package and especially the move with velocity.

Everything is working well with the panGesture, the properties `velocityX` & `veloctyY` exists from the event response and I want to take care of the velocity (speed of the movement). How can I use these variables as multiplicators?

Thanks in advance

Regards